# Reduce giving errors for multidimensional array sum js

Tags: javascript, reduce

*Getting error arr.reduce is not a function for multidimensional arrays - works fine for simple arrays - not sure what's going wrong?*

````
let arr = [4, [5, 7]]
let sum = 0

const calculateSum = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, currentVal) {
    const isEntryArray = Array.isArray(currentVal)
    if (isEntryArray) {
      acc= acc + calculateSum(currentVal)
    } else {
      acc = acc + currentVal
    }
    return acc
  }, 0)
}
console.log(calculateSum(arr))
console.log(sum) ```
````

Comment: Running this in the browser console doesn't give an error... perhaps your last edit fixed it?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a recursive function [flatten the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and then use reduce to calculate the sum.

```js
const arr = [4, [5, 7, [12, [1, 2]]]];

function calculateSum(arr) {
  return arr.flat(Infinity).reduce(function (acc, c) {
    return acc + c;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(calculateSum(arr));
```

Comment: `.flat(Infinity)` is slick.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a boolean not an array when you do:

```
acc= acc + calculateSum(isEntryArray)
                        // ^^^ from Array.isArray()
```

I believe what you wanted was to pass in the current sub array

```
acc= acc + calculateSum(currentVal)
```